# NSMutableURLRequest to post data to URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest, nsmutableurlrequest

I am currently using the following code to attempt at a NSMutableURLRequest.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:allStrings]];
[postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:postRequest delegate:self];
```

I do not know how to actually initiate the post. What actually fires it off at the URL? I have everything setup but *conn is not being used yet, so how do I use *conn?

Answer (score 1):

Creating the `NSURLConnection` will fire the connection.

Now you have to implement the callbacks, esp. `connectionDidFinishLoading` to get the results.

Here are the methods for the [NSURLConnectionDataDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html). From the `NSURLConnection` `initWithRequest:delegate:` docs:

> **Discussion**
>   This is equivalent to calling initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately: and passing YES for startImmediately.

Comment: I don't need to get any info back, so is it safe to just put (void) in front of the NSURLConnection?

Comment: Just don't assign the result. `[[NSURLConnection alloc...`

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many way to start an `NSURLConnection`.

```
[NSURLConnection initWithRequest:postRequest delegate:self];
```

> Returns an initialized URL connection and begins to load the data for
>   the URL request.

So it's weird to have an unused variable you can start it manually :

```
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:postRequest delegate:self startImmediatly:NO];
[conn start];
```

Or not get the result

```
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:postRequest delegate:self];
```

Or even better to retain the NSURLConnection, store it in a property :

```
self.URLConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:postRequest delegate:self];
```

Note there are now two convenient helpers methods :

```
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:];
```

Which returns a `NSData`

or

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:];
```

You can directly use block as a callback.